# SG3525A for modulating an audio signal for a class D audio amplifier

Tags: audio, power-electronics, schematics, modulation, class-d

I am using the SG3525A IC to modulate an audio signal into PWM that is then used to drive MOSFETS for a class D audio amplifier. I have managed to design a circuit that outputs a 10kHz PWM signal.

I do not know which pin of the IC I should connect the audio signal to. Could someone tell me which pin of the IC I should feed the audio signal into?

The schematic below is the circuit I designed so far:

[image: SG3525A schematic]

Comment: 10kHz is far too low. Unless you only want to drive subwoofers with extremely low audio frequencies.

Comment: And, by the way, 3525 PWM outputs are not complementary but they both span together from 0 to nearly 50%. That IC is not made to drive a class D amplifier but a forward converter instead.

Comment: If you think you can just connect a speaker to the output of a class D amplifier, you may need to read up some more. In certain cases it is possible (woofers, special conditions apply), but those are exceptions, rather than rules.

Comment: @frantisek can you ask a specific question?

Comment: I know that 10kHz is too low but i will change the frequency to 100kHz once i get the circuit working but im not sure which pin to connect the audio signal to.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a possible input configuration from the test setup in [ON semiconductor datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/sg3525a-d.pdf). 
You would apply your audio signal (eventually) to the wiper of the POT. You will need to find proper bias and matching impedance. The coupling may look like Pi-HPF, R_shunt-C_series-R_shunt. The first problem will be the offset, the minimum PWM.

[image]

Below is a possible output configuration from the [ST datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sg3525.pdf), page 9 has examples of drive circuitries.
You may want to replace T1 with "high-side-driver" & "low-side-driver". T2 is the speaker. Class D uses the inductive nature of the speaker.

[image]

Comment: yhh. i can just work out how to drive the MOSFETs but i just need to know which pin to connect the audio signal in order to modulate the ICs output

Comment: @FrantisekBalaz ,  this answer has been revised.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am using the SG3525A IC to modulate an audio signal into PWM that is
> then used to drive MOSFETS for a class D audio amplifier*

You might be incorrect in your way of thinking about how the [SG3525A](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/sg3525a-d.pdf) works: -

[image]

It isn't like a H-bridge output because the PWM controls the width of both red and blue pulses as shown above. In between the red and blue pulse at the FLIP/FLOP transition is a small amount of dead time to prevent driving two MOSFETs at the same time. This suits a push-pull circuit that is transformer based like this: -

[image]

So, unless you have an output stage like the above I don't think you can use it to drive MOSFETs in a class D amplifier. And, it's unlikely that anyone will use a transformer to drive MOSFETs for PWM audio applications.

> *thanks id appreciate any advice.*

Probably not the advice you might have been expecting of course.